# How to leverage JSON validation and syntax highlight

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am writing an VSCode extension for a definition language which is based on JSON format, add some grammar and the file extension is still *.json. Once I create a new language id for this new language, the existing JSON syntax highlight and basic validation disappears. Is there any way to leverage JSON syntax highlight, bracket auto-close and JSON format validation in my VSCode extension? Is there any document or example to follow?

Comment: modify the existing JSON TextMate file and add you own grammer stuff and use that to define your new language, also copy the language definition (brackets/comments) file from the original JSON extension

Comment: @rioV8 will that also enable JSON syntax checking (i.e. the list of items that appears in the Problems tab)?

Comment: No, you have replaced the language extension. You can use [JSON Validate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-json-validate)

Comment: you can read the documentation from viscode https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide or read this https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/colorizer/